# How to use the variable names as titles in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

The default ggplot axis titles are the variable names:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, wt)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I want to change my plot so that the x-axis title is instead the *subtitle*. I.e., something like `+ labs(x = NULL, subtitle = "cyl")`. Is there a generalized way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try -

```
library(ggplot2)

plot_data <- function(data, xvar, yvar) {
  name <- deparse(substitute(xvar))
  ggplot(data, aes({{xvar}}, {{yvar}})) +
    geom_point() + 
    labs(x = NULL, subtitle = name)
}

plot_data(mtcars, cyl, wt)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your reason is to put it as a subtitle. Perhaps it is more worthwhile to simply move the position of the x-axis label?

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, wt)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top")
```

Comment: This also alters the axis which is beyond what I'm looking for

Comment: In what sense do you mean that it alters the axis?